# search folder for any subfolder with name specified by me and get its id

Tags: php, google-drive-api

hello I am trying to do a search on a google drive folder, if the subfolder exists then I get the id of the subfolder if not then I need to create it and get its id so i can upload files to it later.

all of the searches will be within the main folder and also i am trying to find if the folder exists based on its name i am using php for this,

so far i have managed using var_dump to get array like this in the image with the id I am trying to find included with some gibberish there maybe if there is a way to clean it up

```
    $mainfolderId = "1CpRAH5PTisqdfsdqfsIAsdfsdoyfuELsVixBtJA"; // main folder where evrthing is saved don't edit
    $folderName = "one ya"; // Please set the series folder name here.
    $optParams = array(
      'pageSize' => 10,
      'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files',
      'q' => "name = '".$folderName."' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' "
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    print_r($results);
```

and this is what i get ( i have used a tool to make it more pleasent to look at) i also removed the rest be its too much you can also see ["id"]=> string(33) is the one i need

```
object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#81 (76) {
["collection_key":protected]=> string(6) "spaces"
["appProperties"]=> NULL
["capabilitiesType":protected]=> string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=> string(0) ""
["contentHintsType":protected]=> string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
["contentHintsDataType":protected]=> string(0) ""
["contentRestrictionsType":protected]=> string(39) "Google_Service_Drive_ContentRestriction"
["contentRestrictionsDataType":protected]=> string(5) "array"
["copyRequiresWriterPermission"]=> bool(false)
["createdTime"]=> string(24) "2021-01-24T09:22:59.645Z"
["description"]=> NULL
["driveId"]=> NULL
["explicitlyTrashed"]=> bool(false)
["exportLinks"]=> NULL
["fileExtension"]=> NULL
["folderColorRgb"]=> string(7) "#8f8f8f"
["fullFileExtension"]=> NULL
["hasAugmentedPermissions"]=> NULL
["hasThumbnail"]=> bool(false)
["headRevisionId"]=> NULL
["iconLink"]=> string(96) "hisddddddddennn by me "
["id"]=> string(33) "1XAmpgAVPudqFzfRoMAny"  <----------- thiiiiiiiisss
["imageMediaMetadataType":protected]=> string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata"
["imageMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=> string(0) ""
["isAppAuthorized"]=> bool(false)
["kind"]=> string(10) "drive#file"
["lastModifyingUserType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
["lastModifyingUserDataType":protected]=>
```

Comment: So it's an object. It either has a) public properties or b) a public getter of some kind. Searching the object class gives the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile.html) for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and the current situation as follows.

- You want to check whether the folder of `$folderName` is existing in the specific folder of `$mainfolderId`.
- When the folder of `$folderName` is existing, you want to retrieve the folder ID.
- When the folder of `$folderName` is NOT existing, you want to create new folder with the folder name of `$folderName` and retrieve the folder ID.
- You want to achieve this using Drive API v3 with googleapis for PHP.
- You have already been able to retrieve the file metadata using Drive API.

#### Modification points:

- In your script,

  - `$mainfolderId` is not used. In this case, in order to search the folder in the specific folder, `'{$mainfolderId}' in parents` is required to be used.
  - The script for checking whether the folder of `$folderName` is existing in the specific folder is required to be added.
  - The script for creating new folder is required to be added.

When above points are reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
$mainfolderId = "###";  // Please set the folder ID you want to search folder.
$folderName = "###";  // Please set the folder name you want to search.

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$folders = $service->files->listFiles(array("q" => "name='{$folderName}' and '{$mainfolderId}' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"));
$folderId = '';
if (count($folders->getFiles()) == 0) {
    $f = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $f->setName($folderName);
    $f->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
    $f->setParents(array($mainfolderId));
    $folderId = $service->files->create($f)->getId();
} else {
    $folderId = $folders->getFiles()[0]->getId();
}
print($folderId);
```

- In this modified script, the script for retrieving `$client` is not shown. Because I thought that from your script and question, the script for authorizing scopes has already been prepared. If you are required to know the script, please check the Quickstart for PHP. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)
- When above script is used, when the folder of `$folderName` is existing in the folder of `$mainfolderId`, the folder ID of the existing folder is returned. And, when the folder of `$folderName` is NOT existing in the folder of `$mainfolderId`, new folder is created and the created folder ID is returned.

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that your `$service` can be used for creating new folder. Please be careful this.
- If an error related to the scopes, please use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: @Seddek Iguijji Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.